# oracle sql query : Getting all entries in a table with the same ID as separate columns

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, report

I have two tables... let's call them employee and phonelist that can be joined based upon the emp_id value.

`employee` has a `emp_id, firstname, lastname`.
`phonelist` has a `emp_id, phonetype, phonenumber`.

An employee can have any number of phone numbers.  There's a fixed list of values in `phonetype`, but for this example, let's just say "work", "cell", "home".

I'm trying to generate a query to generate a report with all phone numbers for employees.  However, they want one line per employee and each `phonetype`/`phonenumber` pair to appear to the right.

So I'm attempting to generate a query to put together a list of values like this, where every employee has exactly one row of data.  And if there's no value for the phone number, it'd just be blank.

```
FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, WORKNUMBER, CELLNUMBER, HOMENUMBER
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear if you need separate columns. If you can get away with string concatenation, have a look at [LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like the following:

```
SELECT e.FIRSTNAME,
       e.LASTNAME,
       wp.PHONENUMBER AS WORKNUMBER,
       cp.PHONENUMBER AS CELLNUMBER,
       hp.PHONENUMBER AS HOMENUMBER
  FROM EMPLOYEE e
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PHONELIST wp
    ON wp.EMP_ID = e.EMP_ID AND
       wp.PHONETYPE = 'work'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PHONELIST cp
    ON cp.EMP_ID = e.EMP_ID AND
       cp.PHONETYPE = 'cell'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PHONELIST hp
    ON hp.EMP_ID = e.EMP_ID AND
       hp.PHONETYPE = 'home'
```

Optional (LEFT OUTER) joins used here because you can't be certain that everyone has a work, cell, and/or home phone number.

Comment: PERFECT.  I was doing the joins,. but didn't know you could add additional clauses in the join... (was trying to do it in the where section and got all screwed up)